# Derivative of an integral (exact differential equation)

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am working on exact differential equations. If I have $H : D \rightarrow R $
$$H(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x_t,y_t)(x-x_0)+g(x_t,y_t)(y-y_0)dt \quad x_0,y_0 \in D$$
Where $(x_t,y_t)=(tx+(1-t)x_0,ty+(1-t)y_0)$ 
I would like to know how to compute : 
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}(x,y)$$
I don't know how to deal with this...

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily call the integrand $F(x,y,t)$. You are told that
\begin{equation}
H(x,y) = \int_0^1 F(x,y,t) \, dt.
\end{equation}
If you want to differentiate $H$ with respect to $x$, you need to make use of the [Leibniz Integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Proof_of_basic_form) for differentiating under the integral sign. The version of the rule I'm using can easily be deduced from the "basic form" shown in the wikipedia page. So, we have that
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial x}(x,y) = \int_0^1 \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,t) \, dt.
\end{equation}
Now, $F$ is a sum of two terms; for the first term, we need to apply the product rule. I'll leave these small details to you, the final answer I got is:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial x}(x,y) = \int_0^1 \left[ \left( \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_t, y_t) \cdot t \right) \cdot (x-x_0) + f(x_t, y_t) + \left( \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_t, y_t) \cdot t \right) \cdot (y-y_0) \right] \, dt
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes thank you !